# ASP.NET + bootstrap styles not working

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I've just started working with Bootstrap.

I need a form like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVPEy.png

Here's my page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/styles")
    <title>Webstite Evaluation Tool</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="input-append">
        <input class="span2" id="appendedInputButton" type="text">
        <button class="btn" type="button">Go!</button>
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
</body>
</html>
```

Bundles:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/styles").Include(
            "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
            "~/Content/bootstrap-responsive.css",
            "~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css",
            "~/Content/bars.css"
            ));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"
            ));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"
            ));
```

All I have in result is this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNXXu.png

What should I do to fix this? It seems not all styles loaded, but in the source code I see everything from bundles.

Comment: check the console, are there any errors for missing css or js files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at button addons in the [Bootstrap Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons). e.g.

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
        </span>
      </div><!-- /input-group -->
    </div><!-- /.col-lg-3 -->
  </div><!-- /.row -->
```

Example at [Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/kwPwHkyrxk)